# I can't ssh into my ec2 instance, says server closed connection

Tags: linux, networking, php, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have no idea why this is happening but everytime I ssh into my ec2 linux instance using any of my ssh clients(putty, mobaxterm, winscp) i get this error:

```
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Before this issue, i remember i closed an SSH session while the server was running some "lookup" type command. It took to long so I cancelled the session and at that point I can't SSH using any of my ssh clients. I rebooted my ec2 instance, and it has been 1 hour since still no success.

Comment: What does ssh -vvv says? Also if you have another server in your account then detach the root disk of this server and attach it to another server and fix any issue related to permission and all. You can check the auth log too for specific issue. This is the most common way to fix issue at aws when you are completely unable to log in to the server also you can check log at aws console log.

Answer (score 1):

don't panic.  If you don't make it in, you are not dead.  You can always image the instance and create a new instance based on it.

In AWS console browse to EC2 | Instances | Instances , right click on the instance you can't get into and select 'Image->Create Image'.
Head over to EC2 | Elastic Block Store | Snapshots.  When the new snapshot reaches 100%, you can head on over to... EC2 | IMAGES | AMIs, right click on the new image, select launch, and go through the instance launch wizard per usual...

When you're done, you'll have a new instance with a fresh SSH config.  All your stuff will be there.

Comment: does it means that you have to duplicate an instance to solve this problem?

Comment: @Richard Probably not... Pratap had some other ideas above.  I like his 'nuclear option' better than mine, actually.